# How do I create an events observer that only calls when the REST API dispatches events?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, rest-api

I just want to call an event observer when the event is dispatched via the REST API. Like if an order is placed from a mobile application, only then the `sales_order_save_after`Observer should be called.

How do I write code for the same in `events.xml`? Or do we have to write somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to place a `events.xml` in the `webapi_rest` area: `app/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/webapi_rest/events.xml`

By placing the events.xml in the `webapi_rest`directory the observer only listens to events dispatched in that area.

You can read about the [areas](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_and_areas.html) and [events](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html) in the devdocs.

Comment: How can i print what event currently i am using into log file @Daniel

Comment: @zus You'll need to inject `\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` to write to the log. WIth `$observer->getEventName()` you can get the current event name.

Comment: For magento 1, how can i do that?

Comment: here is my code, not working https://paste.ofcode.org/UuYfuMtnh84raJux5rUF8A

Comment: Sorry I don't know for Magento 1. You might ask a separate question for this.

Comment: here is my post -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/285292/57334

Answer (score 4):

You can declare your observer at the following location to call it via the REST API only.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/webapi_rest/events.xml

Comment: How can i print what event currently i am using into log file @Dinesh